# Click event on Custom Control isn't firing (event assigned from containing form)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have the following control, which just has a TreeView and ToolStrip dropped on it:

```
public partial class MyTreeView : UserControl
{
    private string _nodeName;
    public string NodeName { get { return _nodeName;} }

    public MyTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void trv_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node == null || e.Node.Parent == null || e.Node.Parent.Parent == null)
            return;

        nodeName = e.Node.Parent.Parent.Text + @"\" + e.Node.Parent.Text + @"\" + e.Node.Text;
    }

}
```

Then in my main form, which contains an instance of `MyTreeView`, I tried to add a Click event there:

```
    private void mtv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(mtv.NodeName.ToString());
    }
```

The `AfterSelect` event fires and `nodeName` contains the expected value, but `Click` does not trigger.

Ultimately I'm going to be loading a file and displaying its contents in a textbox when the TreeView selection changes, but I can't figure out how to 'notify' the form the selection changed happened on the custom control.

Comment: Do you want to get `nodeName` value which is updating in custom control in AfterSelect Event?

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid Yes, I'd like to set a value in `MyTreeView` when the user selects a node. Then I'd like for the form to perform `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(myTreeView.NodeName);` but again I can't seem to figure out how to know when to access the value on the form side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public partial class MyTreeView : UserControl
{
    public delegate void ValueSelectedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string value);
    public event ValueSelectedHandler OnValueSelected;
    private string _nodeName;
    public string NodeName { get { return _nodeName;} }

    public MyTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void trv_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node == null || e.Node.Parent == null || e.Node.Parent.Parent == null)
            return;

        nodeName = e.Node.Parent.Parent.Text + @"\" + e.Node.Parent.Text + @"\" + e.Node.Text;
        if(OnValueSelected!=null)
        {
            OnValueSelected(sender, e, nodeName);
        }
    }    
}
```

Now in your form

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myTreeView1.OnValueSelected += ValueSelected;
}
private void ValueSelected(object sender, EventArgs e, string value)
{
    MessageBox.Show(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Small typo you have `EventArg` and not `EventArgs` in your `private void ValueSelected`.

Comment: @sab669 Thanks to find out the spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this.
    rewrite your control like this.

```
public partial class MyTreeView : UserControl
    {
        //create a custom event
        [Browsable(true)]
        public event TreeViewEventHandler AfterSelect;
        public MyTreeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

            if (AfterSelect != null) {
               //raise the event , as it is subscribed may be in winform
                AfterSelect.Invoke(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

and now in win form subscirbe after Select Event of MytreeView Control.

```
public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

          //subscribe myTreeView1.AfterSelect event
            myTreeView1.AfterSelect += new TreeViewEventHandler(myTreeView1_AfterSelect);
        }

    private void myTreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        //cast sender into TreeView
        TreeView tree = sender as TreeView;
        if (tree != null) { 
          //do your logic here
        }
    }
```